# What does it mean to say that "there is in general a phase angle between the time dependence of the electric and magnetic vectors"?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, maxwell-equations

I am told that Maxwell's equations take the form

$$\text{curl} \ \mathbf{E} = - \mu j \omega \mathbf{H}, \ \ \ \ \ \text{curl} \ \mathbf{H} = (\sigma + \epsilon j \omega) \mathbf{E},$$

where $\sigma$ is the conductivity, the dielectric constant is $\kappa_e = \epsilon / \epsilon_0$, the magnetic permeability is $\kappa_m = \mu / \mu_0$, $j = \sqrt{-1}$, and $\omega$ is the angular frequency.

I am then told that these equations have a simple solution in the form of a plane wave, propagated along a given direction, such as the $z$-axis, so that each component of $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{H}$ varies with $t$ and $z$ with the exponential $e^{j \omega t - \gamma_0 z}$, where $\gamma_0$, the propagation constant, is given by

$$\gamma_0 = \alpha_0 + j \beta_0 = \sqrt{-\omega^2(\epsilon - j\sigma/\omega)\mu} \tag{1.1}$$

For a non-conducting medium, we see in (1.1) that $\alpha_0$ is zero, the propagation constant is imaginary, and we have propagation without attenuation, with a velocity of $\omega/\beta_0 = 1/\sqrt{\epsilon \mu}$, and wavelength $2\pi/\beta_0$:

$$\sigma = 0: \ \ \ \ \ \gamma_0 = \sqrt{-\omega^2 \epsilon \mu} = j \sqrt{\omega^2 \epsilon \mu} = j \beta_0$$

For a conducting medium, on the other hand, there is attenuation, $\alpha_0$ being the attenuation constant. We always choose the sign of the square root in (1.1) that makes $\alpha_0$ and $\beta_0$ positive (they will either both be positive or both be negative), and if we wish the other square root, we indicate it by $-\gamma_0$.

I am then told that the plane wave we are considering is polarized and has its electric and magnetic vectors at right angles to each other, and to the direction of propagation. We may take $\mathbf{E}$ along the $x$-axis, $\mathbf{H}$ along the $y$-axis, and we then find that the ratio $E_x/H_y$ equals $Z_0$, where

$$Z_0 = \sqrt{\dfrac{\mu}{\epsilon - j \sigma/\omega}}$$

I am told that $Z_0$ has the dimensions of a resistance and is called the wave impedance of the medium. I am then told that, since it, like the propagation constant, is complex in a conducting medium, there is in general a phase angle between the time dependence of the electric and magnetic vectors.

I am confused by this last part. What does it mean to say that "there is in general a phase angle between the time dependence of the electric and magnetic vectors"?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to see this may be by using the fact that any complex number $v=v_{\rm r}+jv_{\rm i}$ may be written as $\sqrt{(v^{2}_{\rm r}+v^{2}_{\rm i})}e^{j\tan^{-1}(\frac{v_{\rm i}}{v_{\rm r}})}=|v|e^{j\phi_{v}}$. Here we can choose $v=\epsilon-j\frac{\sigma}{\omega}$ with the complex conjugate $v^{*}=\epsilon+j\frac{\sigma}{\omega}$. To obtain the magnitude of any complex number we have $|v|^{2}=vv^{*}$. Thus, here $|v|=\sqrt{\epsilon^{2}+(\frac{\sigma}{\omega})^{2}}$. For the phase of any complex number we have $\tan\phi_{v}=\frac{v_{\rm i}}{v_{\rm r}}=-\frac{\sigma}{\omega\epsilon}$. Subsequently,
$$\frac{E_{x}}{H_{y}}=Z_{0}=\left[\frac{\mu}{e^{-j\tan^{-1}(\frac{\sigma}{\omega\epsilon})}\sqrt{\epsilon^{2}+(\frac{\sigma}{\omega})^{2}}}\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}=e^{j\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(\frac{\sigma}{\omega\epsilon})}\left[\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{\epsilon^{2}+(\frac{\sigma}{\omega})^{2}}}\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
Thus, not only the amplitude of $E_{x}$ and $H_{y}$ are related but they also have the phase difference $\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(\frac{\sigma}{\omega\epsilon})$.

Note that the quantities you are working with are defined in the frequency domain and their counterparts in time domain may be denoted with e.g., $\mathcal{E}_{x}(t)$ and $\mathcal{H}_{y}(t)$, respectively. To obtain these quantities you need the Fourier Transform in which the phase term $e^{j\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(\frac{\sigma}{\omega\epsilon})}$ will be added to the usual $e^{j\omega t}$ phasor seen in the definition of the Fourier Transform. Please let me know if you find any errors in the answer or have any other questions. I will be happy to expand more on the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where did you get $$|v|=\sqrt{\epsilon^{2}+(\frac{\sigma}{\omega})^{2}}$$ from?

Comment: @ThePointer For any complex/real number $z$ you can define the magnitude as $|z|^{2}= zz^{*}$ where $z^{*}$ is known as the complex conjugate where the imaginary part has the opposite sign of the imaginary part of $z$. Obviously for a real number $z=z^{*}$. You can Google magnitude of complex number.

Comment: I'm aware of this, but I don't understand where the $\epsilon^{2}+(\frac{\sigma}{\omega})^{2}$ is coming from.

Comment: @ThePointer Pick your complex number as $z=\epsilon-j\frac{\sigma}{\omega}$ then $z^{*}=\epsilon+j\frac{\sigma}{\omega}$, then calculate $zz^{*}$. Does this answer your question?

Comment: But why are we picking $z = \epsilon - j\omega$? There is no $z = \epsilon - j\omega$ that I can see in any of my presented work. The closest thing I can see is $\epsilon - j \sigma/\omega$ in the denominator of $Z_0$.

Comment: @ThePointer Edited my comment.

Comment: I don't see how anything before "subsequently" leads to $$\frac{E_{x}}{H_{y}}=Z_{0}=\left[\frac{\mu}{e^{-j\frac{\sigma}{\omega\epsilon}}\sqrt{\epsilon^{2}+(\frac{\sigma}{\omega})^{2}}}\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}=e^{j\frac{\sigma}{2\omega\epsilon}}\left[\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{\epsilon^{2}+(\frac{\sigma}{\omega})^{2}}}\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$

Comment: Furthermore, $$\frac{E_{x}}{H_{y}}=Z_{0}=\left[\frac{\mu}{e^{-j\frac{\sigma}{\omega\epsilon}}\sqrt{\epsilon^{2}+(\frac{\sigma}{\omega})^{2}}}\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}=e^{j\frac{\sigma}{2\omega\epsilon}}\left[\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{\epsilon^{2}+(\frac{\sigma}{\omega})^{2}}}\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ is not the same as $$Z_0 = \sqrt{\dfrac{\mu}{\epsilon - j \sigma/\omega}},$$ so it really isn't clear to me what the reasoning here is.

Comment: @ThePointer I added some explanations. Based on your questions and comments on the other answer, I think the following Wikipedia link on complex numbers may be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number

Comment: @Newbie: the phase angle $\phi_v$ is not the ratio between imaginary and real part, it is the arctan of this ratio:  $\phi_v = arctan\frac{v_i}{v_r}$.

Comment: @FredericThomas My bad, will correct it. Thanks!

Comment: @ThePointer I'm sorry for misleading you. I fixed the errors in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from $E_x = Z_0 H_y$ we will discuss 2 special cases in order to demonstrate the concept of the phase angle. Remember that the phase angle represent phase shift between both components, or in other words, they are not oscillating in phase.

I)  In a good conductor  the second term of $\epsilon- j\sigma/\omega$ dominates over the first term, and therefore in this case we have:

$$\epsilon- j\sigma/\omega\approx  -j\sigma/\omega$$

If we plug this approximation into the definition of $Z_0$ we get (we recall that we can write the imaginary $j = e^{j\frac{\pi}{2}}$):

$$ Z_0 \approx  \sqrt{\frac{j\mu \omega}{\sigma}} = \sqrt{\frac{\mu\omega}{\sigma}}e^{j\frac{\pi}{4}}  $$

and therefore:

$$E_x(\omega) = \sqrt{\frac{\mu\omega}{\sigma}}e^{j\frac{\pi}{4}}  H_y(\omega)$$

So as one can see there is a phase angle between the electrical and the magnetic field component of $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

II) If the concerned material is a very good isolator we can approximate:

$$\epsilon- j\sigma/\omega\approx  \epsilon$$

In this case $Z_0 = \sqrt{\mu/\epsilon}$ and if $\mu$ and $\epsilon$ are real and the ratio $\mu/\epsilon$ positive, the relationship between the electrical and magnetical field component is :

$$E_x = \sqrt{\mu/\epsilon} H_y$$

In this case there is no phase angle, or in other words, the phase angle is zero.

In the most general case that both parts of $\epsilon-j\sigma/\omega$ contribute significantly, the phase angle will be a ( rather complicated) function of the exact values of $\epsilon$, $\mu$, $\sigma$ and $\omega$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please explain how $j = e^{j\frac{\pi}{4}}$. Also, how does $\epsilon- j\sigma/\omega\approx  -j\sigma/\omega$ imply $Z_0 \approx  \sqrt{\frac{j\mu \omega}{\epsilon}}$? Shouldn't $\epsilon- j\sigma/\omega\approx  -j\sigma/\omega$ imply $Z_0 \approx \sqrt{\dfrac{j \mu \omega}{\sigma}}$?

Comment: @The Pointer: oh yes, I made a couple of mistakes. $j= e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$ therefore the phase angle is: $e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}$. Second $Z_0   \approx  \sqrt{\frac{j\mu \omega}{\sigma}} = \sqrt{\frac{\mu\omega}{\sigma}}e^{j\frac{\pi}{4}}$. Sorry, I was a bit hasty in writing down the answer.

Comment: @The Pointer: I corrected the answer.